# Difference between bluetooth phone call hand off and audio connection in iOS and hands free cars?

Tags: ios, bluetooth

What is the difference between placing a phone call in a car equipped with hands free calling over bluetooth compared to connecting a phone via bluetooth to the same system, but streaming music or maps directions that the stream can't be heard unless the radio system is switched to bluetooth / aux?

I'm curious why a phone call can be handed off while say, listening to fm or xm, but instructions from Google Maps can't be heard unless the radio is switched to bluetooth / aux.

Can this be programmed via iOS or is this a flaw on the side of the car's software?

Comment: The difference is that the handsfree profile is (primarily) used for telephone calls where the driver wants the audio to be interrupted when the phone is in use while the audio streaming profile is just another audio source on the system - the user selects the audio source they want to listen to and don't want it to change without intervention

Comment: Right - I understand that - but the same way the phone app is allowed to interrupt the station, couldn't the same code be put into a maps app (for example) to interrupt also? I've seen other questions about this and when plugged in over USB, the phone "calls itself" so Google Maps can give directions; which is cumbersome at best (by the time the call is established, the directions may be over). Just seams like a short coming, not necessarily a code / system limitation.

Comment: Ok, yes, the maps application could be configured to route its audio over a handsfree audio device.  Siri does this, for example.  It is up to the particular application to examine the available Audio paths and decide which one it wants to use.